# HTTP Status 405: Method Not Allowed When accessing C#.Net WebService

Tags: c#, http, web-services, iis

The WebService exists on Windows Server 2019.
The service is rejecting requests with error HTTP 405 Method Not allowed.
I understood that some configuration is not allowing the coming request method.
However could not figure out what setting is actually preventing it.
Following are some things which I tried. Please point out if you are able to understand the cause.

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyfKk.png) IIS LOG**

```
Line 11181: 2023-07-18 10:29:31 <IPAddress> POST /<WebInterfaceName> - 443 - <IPAddress> Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.42000) - 405 0 1 16
```

**[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VXKz.png) Checked result after setting "All verbs" for WebDAVModule.**

[image]

**[3] Removed WebDAV module from below**

*C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config*

**[4]** Also tried to turn off webDAV publishing feature from windows features but Windows Server 2019 did not allow change of setting

**[5]** Later now I found that since the service file is asmx, the related handlers should allow PUT request. The check on this is remaining.
[image]

Comment: Try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to see details about 405 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.